# How to crawl the reviews on google play store?

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler

In google [play store](https://play.google.com/store?hl=en) under each app (e.g. [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.youtube.tv&hl=en&pli=1)) there is a long list of reviews.

But only a few of them are shown, while the others can be grabbed only when you click the "next" arrow.

How can I efficiently crawl all the reviews for all Apps?

The code I tried:

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen
url = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.youtube.tv&hl=en&pli=1"
response = urlopen(url)
html = response.read().decode("utf-8")
```

or

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen
from selenium import webdriver
# simulate the javascript
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.youtube.tv&hl=en&pli=1")
```

Comment: First read the **terms of service** as this may be illegal.

Answer (score 0):

Crawling Google is probably against the ToS, but it's a bit of a national sport in some circles. (See youtube-dl.) I won't go into too much detail, as I don't believe I'd be doing something good there, but I still would like to tell you I would approach this kind of thing. (Executing JavaScript and simulating button clicks is probably easier to get right and more maintainable, but less efficient.)

1. Open the Network tab in your browser's developer tools.
2. Click whatever button you need to press on the app page.
3. Find the request with the data.
4. Right-click -> Copy -> Copy as cURL

Once you do this, you'll have your entire request copied, including the Google cookie (the whole `-H 'Cookie: ...'`, which in my case was several hundred characters), so delete that first of all. Do not share it with anybody. In fact, you can probably get rid of most other headers too. The important parts are the URL and the `--data` argument.

The data argument is URL-encoded, so you may want to paste it into something like https://www.urldecoder.org/ to get a better overview.

The resulting `--data` argument starts with `[[[136880256,[{"136880256":[null,null,[2,null,[40,`. We don't know what the long base64 string after this is, so we just delete it. (However, it turns out that this string probably implements paging.) So we continue `""]],["com.google.android.youtube.tv",7]]}],null,null,0]]]`, and get rid of the `&at=...` parameter as well. Some probing shows us that `40` means that we are requesting 40 reviews, and changing this to 100 seems to get us 100 reviews. Setting the number above `199` gives us an error, but this particular app appears to have only 150 reviews (in English, anyway?) (or at least the review page only shows up to 150).

Here's an extract from what you're going to get:

```
)]}'

96917
[["af.adr",0,{"136880256":[[["gp:AOqpTOE...
]
]
,1,null,"What a waste of a perfectly good app. The bloody awful bold font...
```